# PHP: power bug - 10^(1/4) == 10?

Tags: php

Why 10^(1/4) is 10? which function should I use to obtain correct result?

My test line is:

```
 echo (10^(100/400)). " vs " . 10;
```

and my output is

```
10 vs 10
```

EDIT:

thanks for answers, I will use pow()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`^` is the [XOR bitwise operator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). Use `pow(10, 1/4)` ([docs](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php)) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Pretend you're a cartoon superhero with [POW](https://www.php.net/pow)!

```
echo pow(10, 1/4);
```

Answer (score 1):

After a quick google search: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php

Use pow(10, 1/4)

I think the ^ is some kind of binary operation, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

What you are actually calculating there is 10, xor (100 integer divided by 400), which is 10 xor 0, which is 10.